# Ubuntu Login loop, can't login either in console

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, login, lightdm, login-screen

I just made a Xubuntu 64-bit system using VirtualBox and I can only log in with guest, when I try to login with my account it just stays in the login screen.

I've seen a similar question ([Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)) but I can't apply any of the answers as I get into a loop too when I try to log in one the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> console.

Obviously I can't use sudo to install the guest additions CD image as I can only do it from guest account.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it might seem really weird but here is the solution if you encounter the same problem :

Simply give a different name to your admin account than your virtual computer name. I had the same troubles with Ubuntu and Mint and the solution worked there too. I know it makes no sense but... it works.